# How do I append a string to form results using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've got a form which posts its results using "get" method. I was wondering how I could add some additional values to these results before they  are submitted.

What I did so far is overload the submit function so I could concat my additional string 
which I wish to pass along with the form results to the destination url.

On regular submit the destination url gets the results as follows:

```
   ..dest url?txtName=e&txtAge=r&gender=mail&select=1
```

What I am attempting to do is append  another string to these results

```
  ..dest url?txtName=e&txtAge=r&gender=mail&select=1|myStringResult
```

I've overloaded the submit

```
    function overLoadSubmit() 
    {
        window.addEventListener('submit', newSubmit, true);
        HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
        HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = newSubmit;
    }
```

The original submit is called after `newSubmit()`, and that's where I would like to append my string.

```
    function newSubmit()
    {           
        var myForm = document.forms[0];
        var s = "|myStringResult";             
        // here is where i would like to append s ,
        // but i can't figure out how to reference the form results  
        // or how to add it to the original submit
    }
```

I've also tried adding an hidden input control

```
    <input type="hidden" id="_body" value="getValues();"/>
```

since myResultString is really long and is in fact an entire html document

```
    function getValues() 
    {
        var _doc = document.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        return '|' + _doc; 
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: While it is tempting to do so, you should never augment host objects or assume that browsers implement prototype inheritance. kangax, [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add a hidden field to the form instead?

```
<input type="hidden" name="myhiddenfield" value="myStringResult">
```

The value will get appended to the URL when the form is submitted.

Comment: o'k i got it to work 
i replaced id with name 
i'm new to javascript :)  , its really annoying
thanks Gauarv .

Comment: I've never tried that, but likely you should use *encodeURLComponent* on the string before assigning it to the input's value.